# UITextView Color of the selected text

Tags: swift, uitextview, selectedtext

If I have `UITextView` with `textview.selectable = true`, and I want to change a selected TextColor using a `UIButton`, How can I do this Using swift?

Comment: Did you find a fix? If yes, please post the correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to change the selected range of the string, you must change the `attributedText` property. You can do something like:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let range = textView.selectedRange
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
    string.addAttributes(attributes, range: textView.selectedRange)
    textView.attributedText = string
    textView.selectedRange = range
}
```

If you want to change the whole string, you can use the technique suggested by CeceXX.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    textView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```